# Django Admin, how to populate select options depending on another select

Tags: django, django-admin

My scenario:

I'm having three tables, Category, Subcategory, Products.
While inserting new product, there are two select boxes

1)1st select is for Category (its working)

2) 2nd is for Subcategory, which should be relevant to the 1st select. Needs to fetch the data from subcategory table.

Subcategory table has category id as a foreign key.
I am a beginner, please somebody help.

Comment: check my answer is that worked?

Comment: Sorry sir, that didn't work, I think there's something more to do. How will the onchange work, where from the function call will take place, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have posted whole set of integration, have you implemented this yet? where are you facing issue.

Comment: Yes sir, i have implemented the whole solution, but no there is no change in behavior, neither any error. Is this using admin template overriding?
Should i put the change_form.html file inside templates/
          |-- admin/
              |-- myapp/
                  |--mymodel/

Comment: have you checked the id of your select tag in html, you have to use it for `change` function in script inside change_form.html

Comment: No put change_form.html inside `templates/ |-- admin/ |-- myapp/ `

Comment: yes, sir i have done it. Now it is returning 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token on (index):18

Comment: can i see your code, if you can share it on github

Comment: Hey @user9106216 i tried it in my local and it is running fine.

Comment: I have uploaded a copy to git, if you could have a look, https://github.com/BinayakSantra/demoecommerce.

Comment: Sure I will check and update you

Comment: Hey buddy i made some changes in your project and sent you a pull requests accept it. hope it will work fine now.

Comment: Is it working? You can accept the answer if everything is working for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You will have to use some JS library I prefer **[`JQuery`](http://jquery.com/)**.

For filling this subcategory field, you have to create a view which will respond with json data.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def get_subcategory(request): 
    id = request.GET.get('id','') 
    result = list(Subcategory.objects.filter(category_id=int(id)).values('id', 'name')) 
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")
```

At urls.py you need to add a pattern to reach the view:

```
url(r'^/getSubcategory/$', views.get_subcategory)
```

Now you have to override **change_from.html** of django admin for your product app to add some JS code to do the magic.

```
your_project
     |-- your_project/
     |-- myapp/
     |-- templates/
          |-- admin/
              |-- myapp/
                  |-- change_form.html  # do not misspell this
```

> **Note:** The location of this file is not important. You can put it
>   inside your app and it will still work. As long as its location can be
>   discovered by django. What's more important is the name of the HTML
>   file has to be the same as the original HTML file name provided by
>   django.

In your **change_form.html**, write somethings like this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %} 

{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }} 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
        $(function(){ 
            // inspect html to check id of category select dropdown.
            $(document).on('change', "select#id_category", function(){ 
                $.getJSON("/getSubcategory/",{id: $(this).val()}, function(j){ 
                     var options = '<option value="">---------</option>'; 
                     for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) { 
                         options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>'; 
                     } 
                     // inspect html to check id of subcategory select dropdown.
                     $("select#id_subcategory").html(options); 
                 }); 
             }); 
         }); 
    </script>
{% endblock %} 
# Create a JS file and put this second script tag in it, that way will be easier to maintain your template.
```

Comment: @User9106216 You can add comment here inspite of commenting under question.

Comment: Sir, sorry to say, but the filtering is not working, I have merged all the requests.

Comment: @user9106216 i have sent you another pull request, now it is working, i have mentioned the problem inn comments there.

Comment: @user9106216 you need to run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, i added a dependency there.

Comment: It's working now sir, thanks for your much needed support. Thank you

Comment: You are a star among human beings, sir.

Answer (score 2):

```
url: path('features/',views.get_features,name='features'),
views: def get_features(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id','')
    cat = Category.objects.get(pk=id) 
    result = list(Feature.objects.filter(category=cat).values('id', 'name')) 
    print(result)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json") 

javascript:             $(function(){ 
        // inspect html to check id of category select dropdown.
        $(document).on('change', "select#category_select_m1", function(){ 
            $.getJSON("features/",{id: $(this).val()}, function(j){ 
                 var options = '<option value="" disabled selected>Choose your feature</option>'; 
                 console.log(j);
                 for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) { 
                     options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>'; 
                 } 
                 // inspect html to check id of subcategory select dropdown.
                 $("select#feature_select_m1").html(options); 
             }); 
         }); 
     });
```

Updated for django 2.1 but not working and thanks to **Satendra**. I can not comment above thats why submitted my problem as answer

Comment: I can't comment to my ascending post, but your works really helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I thank Mr Satendra for his good answer.

Your answer did not work in Django 4.2 and I made some changes to make it work

**views.py**

```
from .models import SubCategory, Category
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json


def get_subcategory(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id', '')
    cat = Category.objects.get(pk=id)
    result = list(SubCategory.objects.filter(category=cat).values('id', 'name'))
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'your app name'

urlpatterns = [
    path('getsubcategory/', views.get_subcategory, name='get-subcategory'),
]
```

**change_form.html**

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load static %}

<div> change form connect</div>
{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
        // inspect html to check id of category select dropdown.
        $(document).on('change', "select#id_category", function(){
            $.getJSON("/getsubcategory/",{id: $(this).val()}, function(j){
                 var options = '<option value="" disabled selected>---------</option>';
                 console.log(j);
                 for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                     options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].name+ '</option>';
                 }
                 // inspect html to check id of subcategory select dropdown.
                 $("select#id_subcategory").html(options);
             });
         });
     });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```