# Django template Sorting search results on dropdown select

Tags: python, django, ajax, faceted-search, django-template-filters

I have a search result django template called search_result.html

In the template, I have a list of products based on my filter criteria. I also have a dropdown to sort the result.

[image]

I would like to sort my result, everytime an option is selected.
I did a bit of research and it seems like I need to use ajax and dictsort, but currently unable to figure out the implementation.

My code returning the search result page.

```
def select(request):
    q1 = request.GET.get('brand')
    q2 = request.GET.get('model')
    q3 = request.GET.get('bodyStyle')
    q4 = request.GET.get('budget')
    q5 = request.GET.get('transmission')

    print(q1)

    cars = product_details.objects.all()

    variables = {'brand_name__icontains':q1,'model_name__icontains':q2,'bodystyle__icontains':q3, 'budget__icontains':q4 , 'transmission__icontains': q5}

    for key, value in variables.items():
        if value is not None:
                        cars = cars.filter(Q(**{key: value}))


    _brands = products.objects.all()

    _models= product_models.objects.all()

    _bodystyles = product_bodystyle.objects.all()

    carsdetails={
        "cars" : cars,
        "brandFilter" : q1,
        "modelFilter" : q2,
        "bodyFilter"  : q3,
        "budgetFilter" : q4,
        "transmissionFilter" : q5,
        "brands" : _brands,
        "models" : _models,
        "bodystyles" : _bodystyles
    }
    return render(request, 'search/search_results.html', carsdetails)
```

Any help in this regard would be awesome.

Comment: You don't need to render it just return the result in a  json, on the template you call it with AJAX request to get the return json and replace the html of the table or whatever you displaying the data.

Comment: Could you please be a bit elaborate? How would I sort it in my div? I am new to both AJAX and Django.

Comment: This [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843768/11225821) is different but it should follow the same order of using django request  to return a json data and AJAX to replace html data live without refreshing the page,